# pandas: normalize values within groups with one reference value per group (groupby? split-apply-combine?)

Tags: pandas

I have a set of measurements; each measurement is one line in a DataFrame. I'd like to add a column to those measurements that reflects the speedup of that measurement compared to a reference. Each measurement is distinguished by its "dataset" and "algorithm", and there's a reference runtime for each dataset-algorithm pair.

```
col = ['program', 'dataset', 'algorithm', 'extra', 'runtime']
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [['program-ref', 'dataset-X', 'algorithm-i', 'x', 1.0],
     ['program-ref', 'dataset-X', 'algorithm-j', 'x', 2.0],
     ['program-ref', 'dataset-Y', 'algorithm-i', 'x', 3.0],
     ['program-ref', 'dataset-Y', 'algorithm-j', 'x', 4.0],
     ['program-B', 'dataset-X', 'algorithm-i', 'x', 5.0],
     ['program-B', 'dataset-X', 'algorithm-j', 'x', 6.0],
     ['program-B', 'dataset-Y', 'algorithm-i', 'x', 7.0],
     ['program-B', 'dataset-Y', 'algorithm-j', 'x', 8.0],
     ['program-C', 'dataset-X', 'algorithm-i', 'x', 9.0],
     ['program-D', 'dataset-X', 'algorithm-j', 'x', 10.0],
     ['program-E', 'dataset-Y', 'algorithm-i', 'x', 11.0],
     ['program-E', 'dataset-Y', 'algorithm-j', 'x', 12.0],
    ], columns=col)
```

I'd like to add a column called 'speedup' where 'speedup' for each measurement is computed as (the reciprocal of) the runtime for the measurement divided by the runtime for the reference measurement (for that dataset-algorithm pair). For instance, in the DataFrame above, 'speedup' for line 5 (program B, dataset X, algorithm i) should be 1/ (5.0 / 1.0).

This seems to be an instance of split-apply-combine (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), but the apply functions shown there are generally aggregates of everything in the group or functions whose inputs are only one particular measurement. Here I need to "apply" the reference measurement to everything in its group.

I also added the 'extra' column above because I'd like the output to be identical to the input except for the new 'speedup' column, whereas groupby appears to want to cull out all "nuisance" columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the setup of your data for accomplishing your goals since there are multiple program names per algorithm-dataset combination. Also note that a `groupby` approach is extraneous given your sample data since there are unique combinations of the program-dataset-algorithm values. Perhaps your real data has different requirements? If so, please update the sample data to reflect the requirement. In the meantime, try the following.

It will be easier to merge the reference values with the rest of the data so that the appropriate values can be more easily associated with each other.

```
ref_df = df.loc[df['program'] == 'program-ref', ['dataset', 'algorithm', 'runtime']]
# EDIT: only include the following line if you wish to remove the reference
# rows from the final output
# df = df.loc[~(df['program'] == 'program-ref')]

new_df = pd.merge(df, ref_df, on=['dataset', 'algorithm'],
                              suffixes=['', '_ref'])

# you don't actually need a groupby since there are unique 
# program-dataset-algorithm combinations.
new_df['speedup'] = 1/(new_df['runtime']/new_df['runtime_ref'])

# optional groupby approach
new_df['speedup'] = new_df.groupby(['program', 'dataset', 'algorithm']).apply(
                           lambda x: 1/(x['runtime']/x['runtime_ref'])).values

>>> new_df.sort_values('program', ascending=False)
        program    dataset    algorithm extra  runtime  runtime_ref   speedup
0   program-ref  dataset-X  algorithm-i     x      1.0          1.0  1.000000
3   program-ref  dataset-X  algorithm-j     x      2.0          2.0  1.000000
6   program-ref  dataset-Y  algorithm-i     x      3.0          3.0  1.000000
9   program-ref  dataset-Y  algorithm-j     x      4.0          4.0  1.000000
8     program-E  dataset-Y  algorithm-i     x     11.0          3.0  0.272727
11    program-E  dataset-Y  algorithm-j     x     12.0          4.0  0.333333
5     program-D  dataset-X  algorithm-j     x     10.0          2.0  0.200000
2     program-C  dataset-X  algorithm-i     x      9.0          1.0  0.111111
1     program-B  dataset-X  algorithm-i     x      5.0          1.0  0.200000
4     program-B  dataset-X  algorithm-j     x      6.0          2.0  0.333333
7     program-B  dataset-Y  algorithm-i     x      7.0          3.0  0.428571
10    program-B  dataset-Y  algorithm-j     x      8.0          4.0  0.500000
```

Comment: Hi @3novak, my data really is set up this way. Each experiment generates a JSON file that contains its parameters, which include program and dataset and algorithm and runtime. I would say the program/dataset/algorithm combination is unique, but you are right, dataset+algorithm does have multiple possible programs. I read the JSON files in with `data_unfiltered = [json.load(open(jf)) for jf in json_input_files]` then `df = json_normalize(data_unfiltered)`.
I'd be happy to accept other suggestions about how you might organize this.

Comment: Can't you split it up the way I demonstrate? If you already have the data in the format you posted, my posted solution should parse it pretty quickly. I can't think of any other ways to process the data in its original format without endless amounts of kludge. Perhaps there is a way, though!

Comment: I understand your approach going in two steps, with perhaps the output of the first step being "the way I demonstrate". Step 1 is add a reference column with the appropriate reference runtime for that row. Step 2 is a trivial apply to generate the speedup I need. That seems like a straightforward approach; I'll give it a whirl now!

Comment: what if I wanted to keep the original 'program-ref' lines in the output, with the understanding that their speedup columns would be non-meaningful (or 1)? Return `new_df + df.loc[df['program'] == 'program-ref']`? Or just don't subset `df`?

Comment: Fantastic. @3novak, super helpful. The use of `merge` was really key here. Much appreciated!